# Need help understanding ida pseudocode

Tags: c++, unsigned, ida, uint64, reversing

I am new to reversing. I have stumbled upon a line of code which I am unable to understand.

```
return (*(_int64(**)(void))(**(_QWORD **)(v1 + 0x3C8) + 0x68LL ))();
```

The code is for arm64 lib. So , what I understood is that it's returning a pointer out as unsigned int64 data type. But , when I try to use it as ,

```
return (unsigned long) ((unsigned long)(v1 + 0x3C8) + 0x68) ;
```

, the result is so out of the unsigned long range , for example one result is `19985131375820901`. Also , _int64 and _QWORD both have the size of 8 bytes and so does unsigned long. So I am a little confused here how is this happening. Can anybody help with the correct interpretation of this pls ?

Comment: this looks a lot like a jnienv function call you can try import the jni.h header file and retype the v1 to struct jnienv if its a jnienv call it should print function name

Answer (score 0):

```
v1 + 0x3C8
```

Yes. This adds `0x3C8` to `v1`. But you seemed to have overlooked something else that happens before `0x68` gets added to it.

```
(_QWORD **)
```

The result of this addition gets casted to a pointer to a pointer to a `_QWORD`. That's what this means in C++.

```
**
```

And dereferenced. Twice. That produces a `_QWORD`, from somewhere. Wherever those pointers lead to.

```
+0x68LL
```

And only then does `0x68` gets added to whatever you have now.

But you're not done yet. There's still more C++ code left that you need to unravel.

```
(_int64(**)(void))
```

This gets now casted to a pointer to a pointer to a function that takes no parameters and returns an `_int64`.

```
*
```

And the pointer dereferenced.

```
()
```

And the function call is finally made, which returns an `_int64` value.

Comment: so , the correct way for doing it should be :-
'''
(_int64)getPtr(getPtr(getPtr(getPtr(v1 + 0x3C8)) + 0x68 ))
'''

Comment: So after looking a bit into pointers what I found is ** is used to point to a certain address inside a multi-dimensional array. Which is what is happening here because this code is actually used to get pointer to a table. Intially it was 1-D so it was simply pointer by (v1 + 0xA0). But now it's multi-dimensional that's why ** is being used. But , still don't understand how my reconstruction is wrong.

Comment: If by "looking a bit into pointers" means "run a Google search and read the results", it's not going to work. Google is not a replacement for a C++ textbook. `**` can be used with "multi-timensional array"s, but that's not what it means. Attempting to reverse-engineer complicated existing code (as I understand to be the source of this question) without fully understanding core C++ fundamental concepts, like pointers, is simply not realistic.